# Add toolbar to parent View controller in containment view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

i have two UIViewControllers which are added as child view controllers to the container view controller.Now I want to add UIToolbar to the container view controller.Can anyone suggest me how to add UIToolbar please.

Answer (score 0):

Using Interface Builder it's quite easy. And for doing it programmatically:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar]; // Add it to your parent view controller.
[toolbar release];
```

Comment: I tried that one and  when i added toolbar as subview childview controller did not display the grid view cell content

Comment: What are the controls you are planning to have on that toolbar? You might want to consider `UITabBarController` instead.